# Flutter - How to fetch and display data from Phpmyadmin in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently facing a problem with Flutter. I'am a Newbie and...

I want to display data from my Phpmyadmin database in a ListView. This is my Flutter code:

Thanks for helping me!

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List data;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull("https://api.myjson.com/bins/qzvwt"),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }
    );

    this.setState(() {
      data = json.decode(response.body);
    });

    print(data[1]["title"]);

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Listviews"), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return new Card(
            child: new Text(data[index]["body"]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And my Database Table user_profile:

Table: user_profile

| id  |  name         |  job        |  city       |  iconurl

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: When i run on emulator the Application open but nothing is display from database

Comment: Look like your PHP code is running fine, can you post your flutter code?

Comment: I posted the flutter code

Comment: @SIGSTACKFAULT How is this Java?

Comment: This is Flutter a Dart-base technology meant to create Mobile application

Comment: I didnt say this is JAVA. It is DART code

Comment: * RTFDs * okay, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. This tutorial helped me solve it. Also please make sure the url for your http request returns an array only

https://camposha.info/course/flutter-mysql/lesson/flutter-php-mysql-fill-listview-with-images-and-text/